# How to prove that the collection of positive semi definite matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

I haven't proceeded much. I have tried to use the properties of determinant or trace maps ("taking the inverse image" idea). But unlike the easier cases of orthogonal matrices or singular matrices, I can't come up with a good argument to prove this one. Is there a way to answer this using same ideas or are there any other approach I can take other than continuity of determinants?

Comment: This set is convex see:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322737/how-to-prove-a-set-of-positive-semi-definite-matrices-forms-a-convex-set so it is connected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Lets say $X$ is the space of all positive semi definite matrices in $M_n(\bf R)$ .

**Claim:** $X$ is  Path wise connected in $M_n (\bf R)$.

For any $A$ and $B \in X$,consider the path $\phi:[0,1] \to X$ defined as   $t \to (1-t)A+tB$,Can you check why its a well defined path in X ? Hence,$X$ is path wise connected.

Comment: $\phi$ is continuous as || $\phi$(x) - $\phi$(y) || = || (B-A) (x-y) || $\leq$ ||| B-A||*|x-y| < $\epsilon$ if I choose $\delta$ as $\epsilon$ || B-A|| and of course $\phi(0) = A$ and $\phi(1) = B$. Thus, $\phi$ is a well defined path.

Comment: Dear @user166305,You also need to prove that for any $t \in [0,1]$,$ \phi(t) \in X$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I had verified that too. It was already there in the link of Tsemo Aristide. $x^T((1-t)A + tB)x = x^T(1-t)Ax + x^T(tB)x \geq 0$ = $(1-t)x^TAx + tx^TBx \geq 0$ as A and B are positive semi definite.

Comment: You're right,bravo!

Comment: typo correction on 1st comment. $\epsilon$/ || B - A ||.

Comment: P.S: Ignore repetition on 3rd comment.